# using P-dropdown component filter Value option doesn't set a default filtered value when the component is initialized

Tags: angular, filter, primeng, primeng-datatable, primeng-dropdowns

I'm using primeng p-drowpdown component to filter a table it's options are coming dynamically
i want to set a default filtered option so that when the component is initialized the table date will be filtered by this default value automatically, i used [filterValue] property and set it the the first option of the dropdown but it still doesn't work

```
                  <th class="text-center filters">
                    <p-columnFilter
                      matchMode="contains"
                      field="Date"
                      [showMenu]="false"
                    >
                      <ng-template
                        pTemplate="filter"
                        let-value
                        let-filter="filterCallback"
                      >
                        <p-dropdown
                          [filterValue]="dateArray[0]"
                          [ngModel]="value"
                          [options]="dateArray"
                          (onChange)="filter($event.value)"
                          placeholder="Date"
                          [showClear]="true"
                          [filter]="true"
                        >
                        </p-dropdown>
                      </ng-template>
                    </p-columnFilter>
                  </th>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using **[(ngModel)]="this.defaultValue"** and in TS file just pass the whatever dropdown's default value you want in **defaultValue** variable. Of course you need to initialize it in the TS file first then use only you can use it in the TS and HTML files.

I Hope this helps you!!

Comment: it passed the value in the filter as if it has been selected but didn't apply it unfortunately

Comment: Can you show me your code. Or whatever you done till now!?